Deployment of react-admin: add static prefix to relative paths
when I run my front-end react-admin project, it generates index.html in which I have:
   <script type="module" crossorigin src="./assets/index-1ebfbf3a.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/index-4aace80f.css">


However, when I upload it to website and considering my Django settings, it expects to find them in:
   <script type="module" crossorigin src="static/assets/index-1ebfbf3a.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/assets/index-4aace80f.css">


How can I add this prefix when I buid my project?
the dist contents will be transfered to static folder under Django root and these are my settings there:
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dist'),
)


I tried to set homepage or start-url in package.json to /static/ but it agains generate index without any prefix.

since I used vite build, setting the homepage didn't work, I found the solution as:
Vite Configuration: Update the base option in vite.config.js to /static/ to ensure all asset paths are prefixed correctly.
